# Riot/Matrix: Link to call person

Tags: riot.im

I would like to make a video call to a specific user by clicking an icon on the Windows Desktop.

Is there a way I can do that?

**Background**

I would like to use Matrix for video conferencing between two locations. The Riot client is, however, too confusing for my users. They need a way to be able to simply click a link/icon that directly will do a full-screen video call to the other location.

It is acceptable if the IT-department needs to do installation and configuration, but after that is done, the users should be able to do video conferencing themselves.